# Sort a mix of created_at and updated_at columns in the same query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8. I would like to have a query, where all items from the `users` table are listed twice, one with created_at column, and second with updated_at column. The result of this array should be in an ascending date order (mix of created_at and updated_at dates).

##### My table:

[image]

##### Expected result:

```
Zoey  2022-10-19 ...
Peter 2022-10-20 ...
Zoey  2022-10-24 ...
Peter 2022-10-31 ...
```

How to do that in Laravel 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create two queries:

```
$result_one = DB::table('table')->select(['name','created_at AS field_date'])->get();
$result_two = DB::table('table')->select(['name','updated_at AS field_date'])->get();
```

Then merge the collections

```
$results = $result_one->merge($result_two);
```

And then you can sort them.

```
$sorted_result = $results->sortBy('field_date');
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you can use the `union()` method in Eloquent. Also, be sure to use `selectRaw()` so you can alias the date columns as `date`. The union will need the columns to have the same name:

```php
$usersCreatedAt = User::selectRaw('name, created_at AS date');
$usersUpdatedAt = User::selectRaw('name, updated_at AS date');

$users = $usersCreatedAt->union($usersUpdatedAt)->orderBy('date')->get();
```

The result would be a collection like this:

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#5108
     all: [
       App\Models\User {#5451
         name: "Zoey",
         date: "2022-10-19 18:46:50",
       },
       App\Models\User {#5467
         name: "Peter",
         date: "2022-10-20 18:47:00",
       },
       App\Models\User {#5443
         name: "Zoey",
         date: "2022-10-24 18:46:55",
       },
       App\Models\User {#5459
         name: "Peter",
         date: "2022-10-31 18:47:06",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Then you can get the array from it using `->toArray()`:

```php
return $users->toArray();
```

Edit: Another good solution by @aynber. That solution uses Query Builder. So it depends on your code style on which you use :)